# How to write javascript code for restaurant

Tags: javascript

[IMage link for my restaurant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUzxg.png)

I need to write a javascript code for restaurant.Need to improve arrays,functions and loops.Who can help ,please answer this.
Thank You.

Comment: Looks like you are not asking programming questions but instead looking for developers for a project.  This is the wrong website for that.  What have you tried? Can we see a sample of your code and specific questions?

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Answer (score 0):

You just take interview and select some candidate(programmer) to it, but I am sure this is not a question to ask here, here you can ask programming helps, programming error problems, doubts in code, also you need to give some code that help us to explain the codes, better you try some code and post a question here ,If you want to know how to ask question, please see once here and ask [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: So I can't get  answer?

Comment: code for restaurant????? there are lots of restaurant, lots of logins, lots of programming effects? you start code first???then we should help you on that your code...I am pretty sure, you wont get everything here..

Comment: see in picture,there are everything written

Comment: That is a task for 1 or 2 full week, no one can do that for you free? you can post this in freelance website(there some one do for that for money).

Comment: 1-2 week?I need only functions,arrays ,and loops for code

Comment: You dont need UI at all? only cosole u want all that tasks? making UI for it should take time, Without UI I am really dont know how we create function,array,loops!!You said in question"Need to improve arrays,functions and loops", where is the excising code to improve???

Comment: Can I find you in facebook,and send 1 example?

Comment: no problem, put your example and drop box and post here, or my facebook id is vangan mohamed nisar mohamed...Here you can get lots of response.....

Comment: Ok,1 minute please

Comment: I send you example in facebook